# Suspending active background threads in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, suspend

On a specific condition, when my timer is fired, I want to suspend all my active background threads and logout of the app. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your background thread needs to check to see if it has been cancelled, either through the `isCancelled` method...

```
if ([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled]) {
    // do cleanup here
    [NSThread exit];
}
```

You can't kill the thread externally because there is no way to know what state the thread might be in and, thus, killing it would produce indeterminate behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use GCD, the tasks dispatched cannot be stopped in anyway.
2. But if you try to use NSOperationQueue, the tasks that are not currently running can be stopped.
3. If you use NSThread or pthread, I think it's hard to stop them without extra efforts.

Comment: Then I think you should add logic like while(true) {if (shouldEnd){return;}}   in the thread function. And the shouldEnd variable should be read in something like mutex to protect among multi-threads